# Browsers deny excess to website LWT (learning with texts) (used with Devserver17) of of the blue because it is considered now unsafe a

Tags: easyphp-devserver

I installed LWT (learning with texts) some days ago using Devserver17 and created a couple of texts with audio and everything worked fine and I collected dozenz of words. But today. I just was using LWT as always but when I came back to the page, my browsers just denied access to LWT (http://127.0.0.1/lwt) claiming the site is unsafe. I tried to solve the problems but I fail so far. Did it happen to you and how can I save this problem.

The last thing I remember before the problem occured, that I wanted to try how I can print a text without itending to print. Afterwards I closed the LWT tap by mistake or it closed by itself and then I I couldnt get access again. No matter I use VPN or not. On screen of Devserver17 now it is only written the following (see file):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hodty.png)

I want to use LwT again